# Pandas merging strings in columns and sorting them

Tags: python, pandas

I have three columns that I would like to merge and order

```
x1 x2   x3   x4
US DE   None None
FR DE   US   None
FR None None None
DE CA   None None
```

What I want to do is merging these four columns in an alphabetical order.

```
merged
DE, US
DE, FR, US
FR
CA, DE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter out `None`s, sorting and join in list comprehension should be very fast:

```
df['merged'] = [', '.join(sorted(filter(None, x))) for x in df.to_numpy()]
```

Alternative with lambda function is slowier:

```
df['merged'] = df.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(sorted(filter(None, x))), axis=1)
print (df)
   x1    x2    x3    x4      merged
0  US    DE  None  None      DE, US
1  FR    DE    US  None  DE, FR, US
2  FR  None  None  None          FR
3  DE    CA  None  None      CA, DE
```

If use pure pandas methods and large `DataFrame` this should be slowiest:

```
s = df.stack().sort_values().groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join)
print (s)
0        DE, US
1    DE, FR, US
2            FR
3        CA, DE
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, for some reason, in the first method, I get FR, FR on the third column. But the second method works

Comment: @DogukanYılmaz - With this data? Or with real?

Comment: @DogukanYılmaz - Are there default index?  Try`df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`  before all solutions.

Comment: Oh great, ok :) that was the issue